# Keep Cursor In Current Position After Find-Replace

Tags: cursor-movement, substitute

How does one keep the cursor in its place after a file-replace using `:%s/find/replace/g` ? I looked at [restoring cursor position](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tips.html#restore-position), but not quite what I was looking for, and I could jump back to previous position using `''`.

Comment: So what are you looking for? Using `''` or `<C-o>` is sort of the answer :-) Do you want it to happen automatically?

Comment: Automatically would be great; I'm hoping to eliminate an extra couple of keys, since I find myself going find-replace a lot, oh and learn something new (_:

Comment: @Carpetsmoker as well as `` ) Actually it looks like this particular question boils down to the issue whether it is possible to find some autocmd event we can listen to and trigger this automatically.

Answer (score 3):

The [anwolib plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3800) has a `:KeepView` command:

```
:KeepView %s/find/replace/g
```

Comment: Is there a way to "enable" `KeepView` for all find-replace operations? I'm trying to minimize typing (_:

Comment: You can create a shorter `:KV` alias command, or even `:kv` using cmdalias.vim. To be even more extreme: `:nnoremap : :KeepView<Space>`

Comment: Aaaand it's still the same two keys as with ```''```.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like:

```
fun! SubstiTute()
    let l = 1
    let limit = line('$')
    while l < limit
        call setline(l, substitute(getline(l), 'this', 'that' , 'gc'))
        let l = l + 1
    endwhile
endfun
```

Using setline() in conjunction with substitute() your jumplist and changelist will not be messed up.